# Have a table with some repeating lines, would like to number them sequentially for each ID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a custom table with some repeating lines in it, general format:

```
ID,  Val
ID1, Value
ID1, Value2
ID2, Value3
ID2, Value4
```

Would like to create an update statement to update a SeqNo column so it would look like:

```
ID,  Val,    SeqNo
ID1, Value,  1
ID1, Value2, 2
ID2, Value3, 3
ID2, Value4, 4
```

The table is already populated and the column is created.

Have tried using row number over partition, I believe that would provide a solution, but having trouble with the syntax.

Comment: Could you post the code sample for row number over partition that you mentioned, even if syntax is wrong? If you edit your question and add this info, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good tutorial for using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...)

I added the following line to my select statement used to populate the table:

ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by Date)

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an updatable CTE with a window function:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id, val) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set seqno = seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#SampleTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #SampleTable

Create table #SampleTable 
(
ID varchar(5),
Val varchar(10),
SeqNo INT
)

insert into #SampleTable(ID,Val) 
values 
('ID1','Value'),
('ID1','Value2'),
('ID2','Value3'),
('ID2','Value4')

UPDATE T SET T.SeqNo=A.SeqNo
FROM #SampleTable T INNER JOIN 
(
    select ID,Val,row_number() over (order by ID,Val) as SeqNo 
    from #SampleTable
) A ON T.ID=A.ID AND T.Val=A.Val

SELECT * FROM #SampleTable
```